# Cocos2d CCMenuItem not responding

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

I'm having some trouble with have a CCMenuItem button work. I've followed all instructions/advice given in previous examples and questions, but nothing seems to work. Whenever I click the button, the image doesn't even change to the new image.

```
CCMenuItem *startButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"Start Button.png" selectedImage:@"Start Button Selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(startGame:)];
startButton.position = ccp(0, 0);
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:startButton, nil];
menu.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/6);
[self addChild:menu];
menu.touchEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: did you enabled touch? 
Self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

Comment: where did you write the above code.? in init?

Comment: It turns out that the problem was that I changed the introLayer transition from CCTransitionFade to CCTransitionScene, which somehow messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use the

```
menu.enabled=YES;
```

that property will control whether touch events are processed. The property you are using (touchEnabled) is a basic property of the CCLayer object (CCMenu extends CCLayer), and that controls whether the layer will receive touch events or not.

Although, the 'enabled' property is set to YES during initialization (its default state). It is possible that by using the other method, you are altering the propagation of touch events. Try first to comment out the line.

Comment: I've tried making it touchEnabled, enabled, both touchEnabled and enabled, and neither, but nothing is working.

Comment: place a breakpoint in the 'selected' method of CCMenuItem, see if execution stops when you touch the button. If it does, track that case to figure out why you are not "seeing" the effect of the touch. If not, put a breakpoint in the ccTouchBegan method of CCMenu. If it breaks, step through to figure out why the menu is not propagating the event to the menuItem. If it does not, touch events are somehow broken ...

Comment: Touch events are somehow broken. I guess I'll just have to mess around with it then.

Comment: It turns out that me changing the introlayer transition from CCTransitionFade to CCTransitionScene screwed things up. Thanks though!